# Wordpress wp_set_object_terms to a parent

Tags: php, wordpress

I have these 2 variables:

```
$mc = "MainCat";
$sc = "SubCat"; //Subcat to $mc
```

To set object term to a product, I have used:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, $mc, 'product_cat');
```

But to set $mc as parent to $sc, how do I do it?

I have tried:

```
wp_set_object_terms($post_id, [$mc, $sc], 'product_cat');
```

But this just puts them both as main categories.

Comment: And also, if I need another subcategory $tc with $sc as parent?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to me, create an array for parent and child slug as below.

I think this may help.

**Updated**

First create parent and child taxonomy and then assign the product post by its `id`. I have not tested but should work.

```
   $parent_term = term_exists('MainCat'); 
   $texonomy_ID = wp_insert_term(
      'SubCat', // the term 
      'product_cat', // the taxonomy
      array(
        'description'=> '',
        'slug' => 'subcat',
        'parent'=> $parent_term['term_id']  // get numeric term id
      )
    );
```

Now, set your `$texonomy_ID` as below.

```
$cat_slugs = $texonomy_ID['term_id']; /* also you can set unique taxonomy ids */

$term_taxonomy_ids = wp_set_object_terms( $post_id, $cat_slugs, 'product_cat' );  

if ( is_wp_error( $term_taxonomy_ids ) ) {
    // There was an error somewhere and the terms couldn't be set.
} else {
    // Success! The post's categories were set.
}
```

Comment: Oh, this did the same as "wp_set_object_terms($post_id, [$applicationType, $mainProductGroup], 'product_cat');"
and did not create a subcategory

Comment: @tryAndroid : Check my updated answer. This may help.

Comment: Does not work properly :( 
"Warning: trim() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given"

Comment: Tried to (string)$cat_slugs, but that gives fatal error